# Programmatically list all public/global attributes on a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, interface

Salesforce has provided some new lightning component interfaces to make communities a bit more customizable. They have provided some documentation for these, but it is weak at best:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_search_and_profile.htm

It seems as though there are additional attributes that can be referenced (for search their example has no actual functionality. What is the search term bound to? How can it be accessed to list records?). Is there a way to say for a given component, list all attribute keys I can access? Something akin to `component.getAttributes()` or `component.getDataKeys()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm) for [`AuraDefinitionBundle`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_auradefinitionbundle.htm) to list all the attributes that a lightning component has but this will not give you a reference to all possible interfaces which can apply to a component. The latter is not possible.

As far as building custom search functionality, there are some resources online ( I Googled *build custom search in Salesforce* ) but this would mean a fully custom solution.